# vue large lists with autoscroll

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to have an autoscrolling log on my page. The log gets dynamically polled from a REST endpoint. The problem now is that this log can get very large so I used [vue-virtual-scroll-list](https://github.com/tangbc/vue-virtual-scroll-list) to display the log. I also want the log to automatically scroll to the bottom unless I scrolled upwards at which point I want to keep the scroll position. For that I used [vue-chat-scroll](https://github.com/theomessin/vue-chat-scroll). The problem now is that the log scroll works fine in the beginning but after a few hundred entries the scrollbar gets completely messed up and not matching the content anymore and also not autoscrolling to the bottom. The vue component I wrote looks like this:

```
Vue.component('log', {
  data: function() {
    return { msgs: [] }
  },

  props: {
    id: { type: String, required: true },
    length: { type: Number, required: true },
    refreshRate: { type: Number, default: 1000 }
  },

  template: 
      '<virtual-list :size="40" :remain="length" class="list-unstyled" :ref="id" v-chat-scroll="{always: false}">\
        <li v-for="msg in msgs" :key="msg.id" :class="logColor(msg.severity)">\
          <pre>[{{ shortTimestamp(msg.timestamp) }}]: {{ msg.message }}</pre>\
        </li>\
      </virtual-list>',

  methods: {
    fetchLogs: function(){
      var session = this.id;
      var start = -this.length;
      if (this.msgs.length > 0)
        start = this.msgs[this.msgs.length - 1].id;

      var vue = this;
      $.post(getUrl("/sessions/" + session + "/log"), JSON.stringify({
        start: start
      })).then(function(data) {
        for(var msg of data){
          vue.msgs.push(msg);
        }
      });
    },

    shortTimestamp: function(time) {
      var fulldate = new Date(time);
      return fulldate.toLocaleTimeString();
    },

    logColor: function(severity) {
      switch (severity) {
        case "Trace":
          return "list-group-item-light";
        case "Debug":
          return "list-group-item-dark";
        case "Information":
          return "list-group-item-info";
        case "Notice":
          return "list-group-item-primary";
        case "Warning":
          return "list-group-item-warning";
        case "Error":
          return "list-group-item-danger";
        case "Critical":
          return "list-group-item-danger";
        case "Fatal":
          return "list-group-item-danger";
      }
    }
  },

  mounted: function() {
    setInterval(function () {
      this.fetchLogs();
    }.bind(this), this.refreshRate); 
  }
})
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I think using  [Vuescroll](https://github.com/wangyi7099/vuescroll) may solve your problem.

- First of all, Vuescroll has [handle-resize](https://wangyi7099.github.io/vuescrolljs/guide/event.html#handle-resize) event that can help you detect the size change of content and react to you.
- Second, Vuescroll has [scrollTo](https://wangyi7099.github.io/vuescrolljs/guide/api.html#scrollto) Api that can help you scroll to any location of the page.
- Finally, but how do you solve the problem of too much data? OK, You can manually tailor the array of your data by listening [handle-scroll](https://wangyi7099.github.io/vuescrolljs/guide/event.html#handle-scroll) event according to your own needs.

Comment: You might have forgotten to mention that vuescroll has a _very_ poor documentation (and issues on github are mainly on chinese or japanese), and the default css they provide only works in Chrome. Their demo pages use custom css which is not documented anywhere. Also, I think your own css rules affect how the plugin will behave (I get different results in every browser), which is ofcourse not documented.

Comment: Only  Chrome, are you kidding me? Perhaps you are using primitive version of Vuescroll.  Now, vuescroll has been compitable to almost all Browsers vue supports. See https://github.com/YvesCoding/vuescroll/issues/52 .  'Issues are mainly Chinese and Janpanese' - Are you sure?  The total count of issues is 42, and Chinese issues are only 19. Perhaps you commented didn't even have a look!

Comment: Just by counting the Chinese titles, I get 21/42, and some issues with English titles actually contain Chinese inside. > 50% = mainly. Either way, I do admit this was a rant due to spending 2 hours or so trying to find a suitable custom scroll. And yes - the default css provided uses the non standard `::-webkit-scrollbar` pseudoelement, which only works in webkit browsers.

Comment: You don't know the method of hiding native bar . We use ::webkit-scroll to hide the mobile scrollbar or something else browsers that don't have a scrollbar gutter. But for most browsers like Chrome or firefox , we use  margin-right: -gutterpx and height: (100% + gutterpx) to hide vertical scrollbar and horizontal scrollbar which can not only work on webkit browsers but also other browsers.  Something about issue I think it is not important because Im a Chinese and have more promotions in China , and Chinese issues are not much more than English issuses.